# unable to compare ip address in python

Tags: python, computer-science

my code looks like this

```
from socket import gethostbyname, gethostname
with open('LoggedIn.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    aList = []
    for line in csvfile.readlines():
        array = line.split(',')
        aList.append(array[2])
ip = gethostbyname(gethostname())

if ip in aList:
    x = 1
else:
    x = 0
```

when I got the user's ip address and there is the same ip address in my LoggedIn.csv file the if statement just return false.

Thank you!

Comment: I always the result of from else which x = 0

Comment: Have you tried to print out values inside `aList` or `ip`?

Comment: yes I did, and my current ip address is something like 143.232.xx.xx and there is same ip address in the csv file

Comment: so how can I make it comparable? str(ip)?

Comment: When I have to do it I just compare two ip's just as strings and worked perfect: `'192.168.1.1' == '192.168.1.1'` Output: True. `'192.168.1.1' in ['192.168.1.1', '127.0.0.1']` Output: True

Comment: It is fine that you have same address inside CSV file but I was asking about values inside `aList` because there should be problem - space or some special char ...

Comment: sry guys, I forgout to line.strip() which make my aList = [ 'xx.xx\n'] and thus unable to compare
thank you guys for the help :)